# How do I Create a RunspaceConnectionInfo object for PowerShell?

Tags: c#, .net, powershell

I am trying to create a Runspace using

`System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace(RunspaceConnectionInfo`

but I can't figure out how to create a **RunspaceConnectionInfo** object.  It is abstract and the only subclass for it I could find was a **WSManConnectionInfo** object.

Am I supposed to create my own RunspaceConnectionInfo subclass?

Comment: Why can't you use `WSManConnectionInfo`? Either use the parameterless constructor to connect to the local computer, or use one of the overloads to specify a remote machine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was doing a bit more digging, and it looks like remote power shell runs over WSMan, so using a WSManConnectionInfo object works fine!

Answer (score 0):

`CreateRunspace` is a static method. You need to invoke it like this:

```
PS D:\> $runspace = [System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceFactory]::CreateRunspace()
PS D:\> $runspace


Events                 :
ThreadOptions          : Default
JobManager             :
RunspaceConfiguration  : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.RunspaceConfigForSingleShell
InitialSessionState    :
Version                : 3.0
RunspaceStateInfo      : BeforeOpen
RunspaceAvailability   : None
ConnectionInfo         :
OriginalConnectionInfo :
LanguageMode           :
ApartmentState         : Unknown
InstanceId             : 49589d51-38db-4532-9914-0fd7f3306819
SessionStateProxy      : System.Management.Automation.Runspaces.SessionStateProxy
Debugger               :



PS D:\>
```